# symfony doctrine entity onetomany mappedby not working

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony and really need some help.
I have a TableList Entity to list all the tables with id, name, description etc.
I also have a TableDesc Entity to list all the fields related to the tables. Each row has table_id as foreign key to TableList that identifies which table.

TableList.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TableBundle\Entity\TableDesc", mappedBy="table")
 */
protected $fields;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->fields = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get fields
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getFields()
{
    return $this->fields;
}
```

TableDesc.php

```
/**
 * @var \TableBundle\Entity\TableList
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TableBundle\Entity\TableList", inversedBy="fields")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="table_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $table;
```

I'm wondering why I always have $fields in TableList equal to null? I do have records in TableList.
Can someone point out what's going wrong? I'm glad to provide more code if necessary.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you check yet in Toolbar bellow of project (if you are in DEV)? To make sure your mapping correct or not, by click on it -> doctrine -> entities mapping. Have any error?

Comment: hi vibol, I've checked the entities mapping, both no errors. for the $fields, symfony doesn't generate for me and I did this by myself. Strangely, if I change to   inversedBy="field" (that is I intentionally make an error) doctrine mapping still says no errors. :( Why is that happening? In my case, what is $fields store? All the TableDesc objects referenced by a table? thanks!

Comment: do I need to add anything else in the database of two tables besides the foreign key for symfony to automatically generate the entity?

Comment: you no need to add something more in database because it generated automatically by Symfony that create as migration file.

Comment: then can you provide some hint why it isn't working? :(

Comment: Please to explain more. How do you use your entities? Where do you instantiate them?

Comment: I use my entities for doing crud for tables in a web. I want to do dynamic generation for submitted forms using the symfony document. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Comment: Can you paste the full code including getters and setters?

Comment: I resolved it. Thanks!