# Symfony OneToMany - ManyToOne entity association not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm training myself on Symfony and struggling with a problem with bidirectional association (very basic) because by *dumping* my entity in a twig template I verify that data is correct but the association is always null.

My problem is like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981479/symfony-doctrine-entity-onetomany-mappedby-not-working) but the solution is not shared.

I read the documentation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#collections) and it seems I follow the right steps.

My db contain a **Parent** table and a **Children** table related by **children.parent_id** as foreign key, both table are popolated and I use DOCTRINE:GENERATE:ENTITIES and DOCTRINE:GENERATE:CRUD.

In Parents class I have:

```
function __construct() {
  $this->lastUpd = new \DateTime();
  $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
}
/*
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Children", mappedBy="parent_id", cascade={"persist"})    
    */
    private $children;
    public function setChildren(ArrayCollection $children) {
        return $this->children = $children;
    }
    public function getChildren() {
        return $this->children;
    }
```

In Children class I have:

```
/**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Parents
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Parents", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="parent_id")
     * })
     */
    private $parent_id;
    /**
     * Set parent_id
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Parents $parent_id
     * @return Parents
     */
    public function setParentID(\AppBundle\Entity\Parents $parent_id= null) {
        $this->parent_id = $parent_id;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get parent_id
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Parents
     */
    public function getParentID() {
        return $this->parent_id;
    }
```

As additional info looking at Simfony profiler (of parents list page) -> Doctrine -> Entities Mapping I found (with no errors) AppBundle\Entity\Parents and AppBundle\Entity\Type (a working unidirectional OneToMany association).

I am sorry to post a so basic error and I bet the solution is simple but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

**note: Im assuming that youre not creating an ArrayCollection of children and adding them en'mass.**

you dont have any `addChild` method (which you need to call).

this is easy with an `ArrayCollection`.

```
public function addChild(Children $child) {
    $this->children->add($child);

}
```

you could also do with a `removeChild` as well.

```
public function removeChild(Children $child) {
    $this->children->removeElement($child);
}
```

then when in your controller.

```
$child = new Children();
$parent->addChild($child);
```

then when you persist the parent object, the children will follow due to the cascade persist.  I would also add `cascade={"remove"}` as well, so when you delete the parent, the children will go to.

Comment: What you suggest to me is usefull and I work on it but what I am expecting is that a Parent entity has a list of related Children entity already _filled_ . From the page listing the Children entities I can _dump_ the correctly related Parent entity. When I add a new Childern I pass to te form a _default_ Parent and that is correctly _persisted_ to the database. So I am still missing something.